# Get XML data through form and send to url in one click

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I have a form to get data from XML-file. With the data I have to perform a new search action and it is therefore necessary to put the data in the url.

I've got it working but you have to push the submit button twice. The first time it get the xml-data the second time it can put the data in the url.

How can I make it work with only one time submit?

I tried with ajax, but the xml is on a extern server (I have no control over it) so I couldn't make that work.

Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

$kt = $_POST['kt'];

$url = 'http://website-to-xml-data?kt='.$kt;
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url); 

$cc= $xml->Type[0]->cc;
$mc = $xml->Type[0]->mc;
$tc = $xml->Type[0]->tc;
 }

echo '<form action="/?merk='.$cc.'&model='.$mc.'&type='.$tc.'" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" name="ktForm" id="ktForm" >
    <input type="text" value="'.$kt.'" size="8" maxlength="8" name="kt"  />
    <input id="subHere" type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit"  />
  </form>';
```

Comment: can use your server as proxy to retrieve xml from remote server

Comment: I don't know how to do it. I have search for info but it looks difficult to me, so I thought maybe there is an other solution

Comment: try this:  http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html

Comment: Ok, I will have a look